# Button function call does not work?

Tags: javascript, html

I want a webpage that has something like this:

Welcome 
[textbox] [textbox] [Multiply!] 
Enter a value to multiply.

represented by this html code:

```js
window.onload = function begin() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Welcome";
}

function multiply(var1, var2) {
  document.getElementById('multiply').innerHTML = var1 * var2
}
```

```html
<body onload="onload();">
  <p id='demo'> </p>

  <form>
    <input type='number' name=num1>
    <input type='number' name=num2>
    <button onclick=multiply(num1, num2)> Multiply! </button>
  </form>

  <p id='multiply'> Enter a value to multiply. </p>

</body>
```

Comment: You're not doing anything to stop the form from being submitted, plus you're missing quotes around the function call in `onclick=multiply(num1, num2)`. Also, where to `num1` and `num2` come from?

Comment: This, as well as your last question, both sound a bit like homework problems in an entry-level web dev class.  What changes have you tried making to resolve the problem prior to posting this question?

Comment: I just noticed that the naming convention of the files is more like of those given during class activity of some sort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You lack `"` in `onclick`, and I changed the script. I also removed unnecessary elements. Just add them back in your codes

**EDIT**

I returned the `<form>` tag and added the `type="button"` attribute to prevent the form from submitting. Thanks to **@Patrick Roberts** and **@Nick Tirrell** for the information

```js
function multiply() {
  var num1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
  var num2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;
  document.getElementById('multiply').innerHTML = num1 * num2
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="num1" type='number'>
  <input id="num2" type='number'>
  <button type="button" onclick="multiply()"> Multiply! </button>
  <p id='multiply'> Enter a value to multiply. </p>
</form>
```

Comment: This kind of brushes the fact about the form submission causing it to fail under the rug without addressing it. Try adding `<form>...</form>` back in and you'll see this fails again until you add `type="button"` to your `<button>`.

Comment: I have noticed that when the `<form>` is there, it is working then suddenly it disappears. I'll try your suggestion

Comment: @NickTirrell I just realized it while editing my answer, I forgot that the default for `<button>` is `type="submit"`, no wonder it disappears

Answer (score 0):

give each input an `id` attribute then use that to get the value(s) to multiply, e.g. `document.getElementById("my-id-1").value`.  Also, use a basic

```
doc.getElementById("my-button").addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    //do your thing.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title> Test </title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form>
          <input type='number' id='num1'>
          <input type='number' id='num2'>
          <button type='button' onclick="multiply()"> Multiply! </button>
        </form>

        <p id='multiply'> Enter a value to multiply. </p>

    <script src="01_using_javascript.js"> </script>
    </body>
</html>

function multiply() {
    var numberOne = document.getElementById('num1').value;
    var numberTwo = document.getElementById('num2').value;
    var multiply = document.getElementById('multiply');
    var multipliedResult = numberOne * numberTwo;
    multiply.innerHTML = multipliedResult;
}
```